# Can I transfer a USA transit visa to a visit visa online without going to the consulate of USA?

Tags: usa, transit-visas, b1-b2-visas

Can I transfer a USA transit visa to a visit visa online without going to the embassy in the USA?

Comment: AFAIK the US doesn’t issue transit visas as such. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @traveller There's a C visa. See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html

Comment: What kind of visa do you actually have? If you have a B1/B2 visa that was issued for the purpose of transit, which you already used, and is still valid (in duration and number of entries), yes, you can use it for any other purpose that is within the allowed activities of a B1/B2 visa. If you have a C visa (which is quite rare), then you would need to apply for a B1/B2 visa. But depending on your place of residence, there are quite a few chances you could not get to the US in any case in the current circumstances.

Comment: @jcaron there were 848 C-1 visas issued in January 2020, which is a bit more than 0.1%, but that doesn't include the combination C-1/D visas, of which there were considerably more (these are issued to crew members).

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.  You must apply for a new visa and pay the visa application fee.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is no such thing as "transferring" a visa from one type to the other. You will have to make a new appointment, fill out the DS-160 again, pay the fee again, and go through basically the same process to get a B-1/B-2 visa. Although not required, they will probably mark your C-1 visa "cancelled without prejudice" to avoid confusion at the border. You can transit on a B-1/B-2 visa, so there's never a need to use the old C-1.

Just to be clear, if you told the consulate you wanted a visa for transit purposes, but you actually have a B-1/B-2 visa in your passport, you already have the correct visa type. There is no need to do anything.